# Linux startup script instead init.d

Tags: linux

newbie question... how can I get my script init script to start when linux boots. Can I just drop a script into the /etc/init.d directory and make manual links to rcX.d?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the distribution. You should look up how to do it for your target.

Comment: Manual links are indistinguishable from automatically created links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/etc/rc.local` is a good candidate for local jobs, and it avoids some of the complexity of using `/etc/init.d/` and similar directories.

Just add a line to `/etc/rc.local` to launch your job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. You can read on this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html